# Using array to determine output instead of if

Tags: php

hello i wonder which code produce better result to make it efficient code. my friend tell me that using array to output result is better than use if.

see example below

```
$result = "";
if($a == 1){
   $result = "a";
}elseif($a == 2){
   $result = "b";
}
```

and for array

```
$array_res = array("1" => "a", "2" => "b");
$result = $array_res[$a];
```

which one produce better result? in performance.

Comment: just write simple php script than will call each variant for 1000000 times, and measure time with microtime function.

Comment: If your values are more complex whan just a costants, the computation of array would be slower, because it'll compute all the values instead of only the needed one

Comment: For the given example code, both return an error, as `$a` is not defined

Comment: If there are millions of possible results, this can affect the efficiency.  but in this example, you could a switch statement which would probably be the most efficient.

Comment: @DanielleCox can you explain **why** that should be the most efficient?

Comment: Sure, no matter what, we have every response mapped in the code. If/elseif's, depending on the version, may involve many decisions. The array will have to have each value assigned before being used (unless PHP is smarter than I assume it is) so now the data may be duplicated before being returned (once in code and once in the variable, although copy on write might fix that).  The switch statement is more readable than either of the other two solutions, and only can still hash straight to the correct value (like the associative array). The character count of the code make make array the best.